# Yii Active Record - WHERE on relations-table

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have the following tables in my mysql database:

```
category (id,name, url)
recipe_categories (category_id, recipe_id)
recipes (id, name, description)
```

The SQL statement I want to realize looks like that:

```
SELECT * FROM recipes r 
INNER JOIN recipe_categories cr ON cr.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN category c ON c.id = cr.category_id
WHERE c.url = "google.de"
```

The two models:

```
<?php
class RecipeCategoryModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'recipe_categories';
    }


    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'recipes'   => array(self::MANY_MANY ,      'RecipeModel',      'recipe_has_categories(recipe_category_id,recipe_id)'),
        );
    }

    public function getActive() {
        return RecipeCategoryModel::model()->with(array(
            'recipes'=>array(
                'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
            ),
        ))->findAll();
    }
}

?>


<?php
class RecipeModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'recipes';
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'categories'    => array(self::MANY_MANY ,      'RecipeCategoryModel',      'recipe_has_categories(recipe_id,recipe_category_id)'),
        );
    }

    public function getMainImage() {

    }

}

?>
```

The problem is the WHERE-clausel. How can I realize this with ActiveRecord (with(), CDbCriteria,...)?

Comment: did you run this query in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: No. Its only for example. I only want to show, that i need to "WHERE" the child table.

Comment: what is your question exactly? Are you getting any error in your query?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I want to realize this with Active Records.

Comment: please post your Yii PHP models, (relations between them must be defined)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. I edited the question. Relations were defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While thinking about the answer for this I had to clean up your db table and Model names a little, as the code provided caused some errors while testing. But I have been able to generate the SQL statement you want - however remember when using Yii's ActiveRecord it uses its own syntax and table aliases.

The result I have is:

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`description` AS `t0_c2`, `categories`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `categories`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `categories`.`url` AS `t1_c2`
FROM `recipe` `t` 
INNER JOIN `recipe2category` `categories_categories` ON (`t`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`recipe_id`) 
INNER JOIN `category` `categories` ON (`categories`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`category_id`) 
WHERE (categories.url = 'google.de')
```

To get a WHERE statement in a Yii CActiveRecord call you need to add a 'condition' or 'compare' into your CDbCriteria or FindAll() params. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#condition-detail and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail

For example:

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$Criteria->with = array(
'categories' => array(
    'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
    ),
);
$Criteria->condition = 'categories.url = :url';
$Criteria->params = array(
    ':url' => 'google.de',
);

$Recipes = Recipe::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```

But for that code to work you'll need my cleaned up db tables and models:

```
TABLE recipe - id, name, description
TABLE recipe2category - category_id, recipe_id
TABLE category - id, name, url
```

Model Recipe.php:

```
<?php
class Recipe extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'recipe';
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'categories'    => array(self::MANY_MANY , 'RecipeCategory', 'recipe2category(recipe_id,category_id)'),
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Model RecipeCategory.php:

```
<?php
class RecipeCategory extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
        'recipes'   => array(self::MANY_MANY , 'Recipe', 'recipe2categoy(category_id,recipe_id)'),
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Hope that's useful.